# What's the different between an async delegate and async method?

Tags: c#

What's the different between an async delegate and async method?

Someone told me they were different in C#, but I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous methods and asynchronous delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418392/asynchronous-methods-and-asynchronous-delegates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegates first.  When you declare one, the compiler automatically generates three methods for the delegate type:

- Invoke(...), taking the same arguments as the delegate declaration
- BeginInvoke(..., AsyncCallback, object) where ... are the declared arguments
- EndInvoke(IAsyncResult)

The Invoke() method calls the delegate target synchronously, just like a plain call.  The BeginInvoke() method is the *asynchronous* call, the target method runs on a thread-pool thread.  The EndInvoke() call is required after the method completes to release resources allocated for the call and to re-raise any exception that might have aborted the call.

The .NET framework contains many classes that have a BeginXxxx() method.  The MSDN Library refers to them as *asynchronous operations*, not asynchronous methods.  They start an operation that completes asynchronously.

Starting with .NET 4.5 and supported by C# version 5, the asynchronous operations whose name end in Async and return a Task can be called in an **await** expression.  When used in a method that has the **async** modifier.  This greatly simplifies dealing with asynchronous operations, important in WinRT where many common operations are asynchronous.

Comment: This is no longer true in C# 5 (Visual Studio Dev11 Preview).  C# does have proper support for "async" methods.

Answer (score 1):

For the differences, as well as some further discussion, see [Asynchronous methods and asynchronous delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418392/asynchronous-methods-and-asynchronous-delegates) right here on SO.